# TypeError: jQuery(...).plugin-name is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm having an issue on my Wordpress site where certain JQuery elements have ceased to function

The main one is relating to an audio player plugin which we use..

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).audio1_html5 is not a function
isProgressInitialized:false
```

When clicking on this in Firebug it comes up with:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery("#lbg_audio1_html5_25").audio1_html5({
            skin:"whiteControllers",
            initialVolume:1,
            autoPlay:false,
            loop:false,
            playerPadding:5,
            playerBg:"#000000",
            bufferEmptyColor:"#929292",
            bufferFullColor:"#454545",
            seekbarColor:"#FFFFFF",
            volumeOffColor:"#454545",
            volumeOnColor:"#FFFFFF",
            timerColor:"#FFFFFF",
            songAuthorTitleColor:"#FFFFFF",
            showRewindBut:true,
            showPlayBut:true,
            showPreviousBut:true,
            showNextBut:true,
            showPlaylistBut:true,
            showVolumeBut:true,             
            showVolumeSliderBut:true,
            showTimer:true,
            showSeekBar:true,
            showAuthor:true,
            showTitle:true,
            showPlaylist:true,              
            showPlaylistOnInit:true,                
            playlistTopPos:2,               
            playlistBgColor:"#000000",
            playlistRecordBgOffColor:"#000000",
            playlistRecordBgOnColor:"#333333",
            playlistRecordBottomBorderOffColor:"#333333",
            playlistRecordBottomBorderOnColor:"#FFFFFF",
            playlistRecordTextOffColor:"#777777",
            playlistRecordTextOnColor:"#FFFFFF",
            numberOfThumbsPerScreen:5,
            playlistPadding:4,
            showPlaylistNumber:true,
            isSliderInitialized:false,
            isProgressInitialized:false     
        });
    });
```

On our homepage there is all manner of errors in Firebug. It looks to me like JQuery has not loaded correctly, however I've tried placing JQuery links first in the header, first in the footer, using both Google and JQuery hosted, and even the latest version:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: check that you are only loading one version of jQuery in page, and it loads before all plugins

Comment: If jQuery wasn't loaded, the error would along the lines `Calling a method of undefined` or `jQuery is undefined`. As far as I know, WordPress now ships with jQuery, so there's no need to plug in another one.

Comment: Are you using this plugin HTML5 Audio Player WordPress Plugin? or any other audio plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following to load jquery properly for wordpress, in your template header.php add this in head section if not there

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>

<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

After the wp_head function add your script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

For more detailed explanation check http://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/